# Jsoup Hanging Without Errors

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I'm having an issue with Jsoup and hanging. I was testing Jsoup code, that was previously working, when out of nowhere it stopped working.  I haven't changed any of the code since about a week ago, and until now, it has been working.

I've been trying to hit Wikipedia's Main Page to scrape links off of it for a homework assignment.

It hangs without throwing me any errors, nor does the program move past the URL connection `.get()` method.  I waited about 10 minutes and still nothing happened.

Below is my code:

```
    private WikiPage pullData(String url, WikiPage parent) {
    WikiPage wp;
    try {

        String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(decodedURL).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a");
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        Element t = doc.select("title").first();

        StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();
        String title = t.text().replace(" - Wikipedia", "");

        paragraphs.forEach(e -> {
            words.append(e.text().toLowerCase());
        });

        wp = new WikiPage(url, title, parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_LINKS; i++) {
            boolean properLink = false;
            while (!properLink) {
                //int rnd = R_G.nextInt(links.size());
                String a = links.get(i).attr("href");
                if (a.length() >= 5 && a.substring(0, 5).equals("/wiki") && containsChecker(a)) {
                    String BASE_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org";
                    String decode = URLDecoder.decode(BASE_URL + a, "UTF-8");
                    wp.addChildren(decode);
                    properLink = true;
                }
            }
        }

        String[] splitWords = words.toString().replaceAll("[_$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!\\[\\]\\-\"/{}]", " ").split(" ");
        for (String s : splitWords) {
            if (s.length() >= 1) {
                wp.addToWords(new WordCount(s, 1, 0));
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%1$-10s %2$-45s\n", counter, title);
        counter++;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return wp;

}
```

Here is a screenshot after running the program for 10 minutes with a break point at `Elements links = doc.select("a");` :

[Before hitting the `.get()` method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4CdD.jpg)

[Hanging for about 10 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoyQL.jpg)

I can't seem to see where the issue lies, and I've even tried different websites, but it just does not work at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to add a timeout at `Jsoup.connect...`, something like: `final Connection connection =
          Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(...);

      final Connection.Response response = connection.execute(); doc = connection.get();` and see if you get a IOẼxception (https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout-int-) and get more info about the source of the problem

Comment: @rperes That still didn't seem to work :(...I'm going to see if Eclipse throws the same issue, it might be Intellij?

Comment: For those like me who ran into the hang problem : upgrade Jsoup to 1.12.1-SHAPSHOT resolved the problem for me.